# TabsController of Material Design is being shown above safe area [iOS, Swift, Material Design]

Tags: ios, swift, material-design

I was trying to use `TabsController` of Material Design in the ViewController. The viewcontrollers of tabs are

```
class ViewControllerOne: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tabItem.title = "One"
    }
}

class ViewControllerTwo: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tabItem.title = "Two"
    }
}
```

And the parent viewcontroller which is connected to the storyboard is,

```
import Material

class NewViewController: TabsController {
    open override func prepare() {
        viewControllers = [ViewControllerOne(), ViewControllerTwo()]
        super.prepare()

        tabBarAlignment = .top
        tabBar.lineAlignment = .bottom
    }
}
```

Now the output is,
[image]

The storyboard is
[image]

How can I bring the tabs under the Safe Area?

Comment: Show how you called your `TabController`. To bring tab under `Safe Area Layout` `TabController` must be inside `UINavigationController(rootViewController: TabController()`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I do not have any other code other than this. I am new to iOS. Could you please tell me more about what do I have to do? Thanks

Comment: Add your full storyboard screenshot or you can share your project in github and put that link in here.

Comment: I have added the storyboard. As I said there is nothing.

Comment: `NewViewController ` how did you call this controller? Is this your first page of the app? If this is your first page then you have written code in `SceneDelegate` or `AppDelegate`. I think it'll be better you provide project files. It'll be easy to understand what have you done and fast to solve your problem.

Comment: I didn't change a single line in appdelegate or scenedelegate and this is only viewcontroller and the entry viewcontroller.